# Ошибка подключения mysql в xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Установил xampp․ на нем версия `mysql 5.0.12-dev`.

При подключении к базе вылезает вот такая ошибка.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. in C:\xampp\htdocs\demovolley\post.php on line 3
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. in C:\xampp\htdocs\demovolley\post.php on line 3
>   Ошибка подключения (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.

Просто создал пустую базу, и на голом `php` пробовал подключится, но та же ошибка.

```
$conect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","******","base_name");
```

Comment: Предположение наугад: в файле hosts соответствующая запись случайно не удалена?

Comment: @andreyma нет нечего там не удалено.

Comment: `$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","root","floralsupply");`